# Why ratsnest is called so?

Tags: cad

In my favorite CAD, [Eagle](http://cadsoft.de), there is a function called "ratsnest", which removes all multisegment airwires and replaces them with one straight airwire.

According to wiki of [some other CAD](http://server.ibfriedrich.com/wiki/ibfwikien/index.php?title=Airwires_/_Ratsnest),

> A multitude of airwires are called ratsnest.

But why is this feature/object has such a weird name? I was not able to find any reference to its history. (It is also possible that it is a well-known construct which I cannot recognize due to my non-English background. If so, can you point me to any dictionary?)

Comment: Could just as well be on [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what a real ratsnest looks like:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/masneyb/2087687407/

"Rat's nest" is an English idiom meaning "[a place of great clutter or disorder.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rat's+nest)
"

Comment: Cool. I didn't knew that rats make nests.

Answer (score 1):

it also looks a lot like the bunch of straw a rat might use to build a nest